# Slack Oauth integration with adam-paterson/oauth2-slack

Tags: php, oauth, slack-api, slack

I am trying to use the Admin-paterson oauth library for PHP to connect to slack

(https://github.com/adam-paterson/oauth2-slack)

When I run the sample code:

```
include("slack-vendor/autoload.php");
include("slacker/src/Provider/Slack.php");
$provider = new \AdamPaterson\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Slack([
 'clientId'          => $$slackid,
 'clientSecret'      => $slacksecret,
 'redirectUri'       => $returnURL,

 ]);

 if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {

 // If we don't have an authorization code then get one
 $authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl();
 $_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $provider->getState();
 header('Location: '.$authUrl);
 exit;

 // Check given state against previously stored one to mitigate CSRF attack
 } elseif (empty($_GET['state']) || ($_GET['state'] !== $_SESSION['oauth2state'])) {

 unset($_SESSION['oauth2state']);
 exit('Invalid state');

 } else {

 // Try to get an access token (using the authorization code grant)
 $token = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
     'code' => $_GET['code']
 ]);

 // Optional: Now you have a token you can look up a users profile data
 try {

     // We got an access token, let's now get the user's details
     $team = $provider->getResourceOwner($token);

     // Use these details to create a new profile
     printf('Hello %s!', $team->getName());

 } catch (Exception $e) {

     // Failed to get user details
     exit('Oh dear...');
 }

 // Use this to interact with an API on the users behalf
 echo $token->getToken();
 }
```

I get an error back from slack saying :

```
 Invalid permissions requested
 Requested scopes cannot be blank
```

I tried adding a "scope" to the call like this:

```
 $provider = new \AdamPaterson\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Slack([
 'clientId'          => $slackid,
 'clientSecret'      => $slacksecret,
 'redirectUri'       => $returnURL,
 'scope' => 'channels:write,groups:write,team:read'
 ]);
```

but it still returns the same error.

When I look at the url the scope field is blank

what do I need to do to send scope to the server?

Answer (score 1):

Add your scope in `getAuthorizationUrl()` method like this

```
 $authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl([
                'scope'         => 'channels:write'
            ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the scope as defined in https://api.slack.com/apps/ in your App, under OAuth, e.g.    'scope' => 'users.profile:read'

Comment: That's a broken link. It's always a good idea to include the relevant content of a link directly in your answer.

Comment: That's the start of a link. The correct look points to my own Apps which are not public. Look in your Slack Dashboard.

Comment: You can't rely on users having a Slack Dashboard.

Comment: Then you probably cannot use this functionality, at least you cannot set it up. This library needs the client ID and the client secret to work, because it connects to the Slack app. These are only available in the Dashboard of that App.

Comment: If you just want to use the Sign-in with Slack as a normal user, someone else has to set up the App for you and also this script.